# How to install Heroku on Termux

Tags: android, heroku, installation, termux

I want to install Heroku on Termux on my Android Tecno droipad but I get this message after each trial:

$ apt install heroku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku

That's what I get when I run the command: $apt install heroku.

What should I do to have heroku installed?

Answer (score 0):

[From this Github repo :](https://github.com/dekubi/hello-world/blob/master/README.md)

> termux-chroot
>
> cd /
>
> wget
>   https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-linux-arm.tar.gz
>
> mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
>
> tar -xvzf heroku-OS-ARCH.tar.gz -C /usr/local/lib
>
> ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
>
> /usr/local/lib/heroku/install
>
> cd /home/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib
>
> mv node node_broken
>
> ln -s /usr/bin/node ./node